# Mercurial and Notepad++ Integration

Tags: version-control, mercurial, notepad++, tortoisehg

Are there plug-ins for Notepad++ to integrate with Mercurial and TortoiseHg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugin exists only for tortoise svn,
you can only semi integrate TortoiseHg with Notepad++ using

```
thg annotate "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

to show the history of the current file for anything else Workbench

Answer (score 10):

If you add the following to our config file you can use Notepad++ to open files.

```
[tortoisehg]
editor = <path\to\>Notepad++.exe ["$FILE" -n$LINENUM] -multiInst -nosession
```

You can get more information at https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/OpenAtLine.

Comment: I had to use `editor = <path\to\>Notepad++.exe -n$LINENUM -multiInst -nosession` otherwise Notepad++ would create a files called "$FILE" and "[".  This was for Notepad++ 5.9.2

Comment: In Notepad++ 6.2.2, the parameters don't seem to be being passed. I can delete the -multiInst and -nosession parameter and Notepad++ still opens in a new instance. It still opens the file, but ignores the line number. [tortoisehg]
editor = C:\Progra~1\Notepa~1\notepad++.exe ["$FILE" -n$LINENUM] -multiInst -nosession

Comment: I had to wrap the full path to Notepad++.exe in quotation marks as it contains spaces. i.e: editor = "c:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" ["$FILE" -n$LINENUM] -multiInst -nosession