# Using other editor with TortoiseHg

Tags: editor, notepad++, tortoisehg, sublimetext2

I'm trying to use other editor with TortoiseHG, instead of (Windows) Notepad.

I have tried the solutions mentioned here:

[Mercurial and Notepad++ Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207880/mercurial-and-notepad-integaration)

and here:

https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/OpenAtLine

But no results. When I right-click a file and choose "Edit Local" no file is opened at all, except when I don't set any specific editor (then file is opened in Notepad).

I have tried different editors, like Notepad++ and Sublime Text 2, and no result. Also, I tried to change configuration using "Setting" in GUI, and editing "C:\Users\<my_user>\mercurial.ini"

For example, I tried:

```
#### # For Sublime Text 2
[tortoisehg]
editor = C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe [$FILE:$LINENUM]

#### # Or, for NotePad++ :
[tortoisehg]
editor = C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe ["$FILE" -n$LINENUM] -multiInst -nosession
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt it will help, but your NotePad++ path looks incorrect (missing "\" between the two instances of "Notepad++") in the above example

Comment: Path corrected. Thanks. I just wrote it wrong here.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but where is that settings file that you are editing? In the repo, or in TortoiseHG install path?

Comment: In windows, C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\Mercurial.ini for site-wide configuration and C:\Documents and Settings\username\Mercurial.ini for per-user configuration. And repo-root\.hg\hgrc for a per-repository configuration.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll kick yourself...

Change:

```
[tortoisehg] 
editor = C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe ["$FILE" -n$LINENUM] -multiInst -nosession
```

To:

```
[tortoisehg]
editor = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" ["$FILE" -n$LINENUM] -multiInst -nosession
```

Note the additional quotes around the path to Notepad++.
I'm guessing it's exactly the same issue with your path to Sublime Text too as both paths contain a space.

Comment: Incredible... how people can be helpful together. ^_^

Comment: Why should we always start new instance of NP++?

Comment: I just kicked myself!

Comment: @hellboy This is late, but I hope it still helps: Certain commands, for example `hg histedit`, wait for the editor process to close and then process the file. Without the new instance, this most likely happens immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Strange editor = C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe without double quotes worked for me

Comment: Since you have no additional arguments, it might as well work